# How to add excerpt in custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom post type in WordPress how I can add custom excerpt add a field in this.  custom post type is saved in the same wp_posts table. and Add option show all the fields. But now I want to add custom excerpt field in this. I there any WordPress function to add an excerpt. anyone can help!

Answer (score 11):

I hope you have created the custom post type by adding the function register_post_type() in theme function.php file. If yes, you just update your code with 'supports'. Then go to Screen Options and click 'Excerpt'.

```
$args = array(
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
);

register_post_type( 'book', $args );
```

Or you can also add the following code

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function my_add_excerpts_to_pages() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' ); //change page with your post type slug.
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Change your support field to this
'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ) );

Answer (score 4):

**How to add excerpt in custom post type in WordPress?**

Example no 1 :

```
<?php
/**
 * Enables the Excerpt meta box in post type edit screen.
 */
function wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_post() {
    add_post_type_support( 'your post type slug name here', 'excerpt' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_post' );
?>
```

more details here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support

Example no 2 :

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_testimonial_posttype' );
function create_testimonial_posttype(){
  register_post_type( 'testimonials',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Testimonials' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Testimonial' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'clients'),
      'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','editor','page-attributes','excerpt'),
    )
  );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

*In top the screen there is an option ie **Screen Options** to add exceprt while adding post. Select expert, and the exceprt field automatically added to the add post page.*